# I don't know what kind of bike this is. I need the name of this frame before I trade somebody

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

I need help identifying this bike. 
I've tried looking up the colors, tried looking up the logo but can't make out what the logo is. Please help

Comment: If you don't know the name, it could be a stolen bike.

Comment: I'd say "if the seller doesn't have any papers about the bike" - receipt, any owners' manuals, etc.

Comment: Is there a headbadge? If so what does it say, or any words on the bike, their is almost always a brand or model written somewhere, and it looks new or barely used. The chainguard and reflectors are suspect as generally anyone that rides BMX would have removed them in the US.

Comment: It's a generic BMX.  Nothing at all to distinguish it.

Answer (score 1):

Its a BMX - but couldn't give a specific brand.

The front or back wheel appears to be a different colour and at least one of them has been replaced.

In addition the tread pattern on the tyres is different, so one of them may be newer than the other.

The gearing looks very small - both the chainring and rear cog look quite small, but that might be partially the white-painted chain.

Also the rear brake is interesting - it appears to be a U brake or a centerpull brake.  There doesn't appear to be a front brake at all, so it may not be road legal (depends where in the world you live.)

The front reflector looks like an afterthought, and the rear one is mostly obscured by the saddle and the rider.  However their presence suggests its for road use.

So it looks like a relatively modern BMX bike intended for road use, but its not a stunts or trials bike.

Comment: The reflectors are probably there because they are required by law, and expected to be removed before use.

Comment: @ojs yes required fitment at time of sale in many locations.  But they are still there now, so its unlikely to have been set up for anything special; therefore its a road-bmx.

Comment: @Criggie as i know the gearing on BMXs is always small like that.